# Creating an image from a bitmap to a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I've been trying to create a bitmap, and use said bitmap to create an image which needs to be shown inside a picturebox. So far Google hasn't been of any help. The bitmap needs to be filled with black/white pixels defined in an array, but I've used Aliceblue for now.

When I run the code I get the error "value cant be null" at this line

```
Bitmap afbeelding = new Bitmap(resolutie, resolutie, g);
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
public void draw(Array array)
{

    Bitmap afbeelding = new Bitmap(resolutie, resolutie, g);

    for(int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < array.Length; y++)
        {
            afbeelding.SetPixel(x, y, Color.AliceBlue);
        }
    }

   pictureBox1.Image = afbeelding;
   //afbeelding = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm not sure how to fill g since there isn't a DrawPixel function in Graphics

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So, what's the problem? Which bit you cannot figure out?

Comment: There is no question in your post. Please tell us what problem you are having.

Comment: If you delete the g from your Bitmap creation your code will work.

Comment: That's what I had before, @TaW, but then it says I've entered invalid parameters

Comment: No it doesn't here. Have you created the Array? I call the function like this in a button: `draw(new Array[66]);`  You will need a Graphics object to use its advanced Drawing methods like FillRectangle or DrawString but to set pixels you don't.. Of course your variable `resolutie` must have a postive integer value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the array contains the definition of an image, you should probably fill the rows of the image with a chunk of the array, instead of filling the image horizontally and vertically with the array.

Let's suppose the array is for a 10 x 10 image, which would make the array 100 bytes long. You need to assign the first 10 bytes to the first row of the image, and so on. You also need to check the value of the array member whether to draw a pixel or not.

Example:

```
public void draw(bool[] array)
{
    Bitmap afbeelding = new Bitmap(resolutieX, resolutieY);

    for(int y = 0; y < resolutieY; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < resolutieX; x++)
        {
            if (array[y * resolutieX + x] == true)
                afbeelding.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
            else
                afbeelding.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
        }
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = afbeelding;
}
```

To test this (assuming you have a button1 on the form):

```
int resolutieX = 100;
int resolutieY = 100;
Random R = new Random();    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool[] bArray = new bool[resolutieX * resolutieY];

    for (int i = 0; i < bArray.Length; i++)
        bArray[i] = R.Next(0, 2) == 1 ? true : false;

    draw(bArray);
}
```

Comment: Already edited, and I did this from the top of my head, so haven't tried compiling it actually.

Comment: sure. I don't know if he really want to end up with a 1-bit bitmap though.. His real problems seem to be each single paramter in the new Bitmap call ;-)

Comment: When  try to run this code it says "The name 'PixelFormat' does not exist in the current context", Do you know how to fix this? It's probably very obvious, but this is the first time I'm working with images and the entire concept still seems rather vague to me

Comment: I forgot you can't set pixels on indexed bitmaps. Just omit it altogether. The above code works; I'll add a test routine in my next edit.

Comment: Your edit did the trick, but why should I use an array of booleans?

Comment: Because if you either want to draw a pixel or not, there's only two options and you can use booleans for that. True if the pixel should be drawn or one color, and false if it should not be drawn or drawn in the other color.

Comment: Once again I'm getting the "invalid input" error, since there is no constructor that requires two int's

Comment: There is and always has been a constructor that takes two int32 values... see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void draw(int[] array)
    {

        Bitmap afbeelding = new Bitmap(11, 11);


        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            afbeelding.SetPixel(array[i], array[i], Color.Black);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = afbeelding;
        //afbeelding = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        draw(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not locking the pixel array? Check this out, it is faster:

[BitmapData Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata(v=vs.90).aspx)